# SQL Server 2012 Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql-server, triggers, syntax-error

I have written a trigger that checks foreign key constraints between two different databases. It works however I wanted to add the ability to identify which record caused the “violation of foreign key constraint” in the RAISERROR.  I added the declared variable @SourceParameterTemplateID to the first SELECT statement making it equal to the field I am looking for. When I do this I receive two “Incorrect Syntax Near” errors.  The first one is on the '=' and the second one is on the last ')'. I have looked for a possible solution however from what I have come across this should work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
Create Trigger AV.testfkTrigger ON [AQB_MON].[AV].[NAAQValue]
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @SourceParameterTemplateID varchar(25)
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 @SourceParameterTemplateID = [SourceParameterTemplateID]
        FROM INSERTED AS I
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM [AVData].[dbo].[SourceParameterTemplate] AS A
            WHERE I.[SourceParameterTemplateID] = A.[SourceParameterTemplateID]
        )
        order by [SourceParameterTemplateID]
    ) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Violation of foreign key constraint',16,1, @SourceParameterTemplateID);
        ROLLBACK;
    END
END
```

Comment: Did you want this: @SourceParameterTemplateID =  SELECT TOP 1  [SourceParameterTemplateID] for line 8?

Comment: It really didn't like that. It placed the "Incorrect Syntax near" error on @SourceParameterTemplateID and made [SourceParameterTemplateID] an invalid column name.

Comment: The CASE WHEN removed the "Incorrect Syntax Near" errors however the trigger worked as the original trigger did without the extra work of putting the extra variable in the RAISERROR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 @SourceParameterTemplateID` results in an syntax error. You can uses `EXIST` and assign to `SourceParameterTemplateID` at the same time. You can get around this by using the following syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AV.testfkTrigger ON [AQB_MON].[AV].[NAAQValue]
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       DECLARE @SourceParameterTemplateID VARCHAR(25)
       SELECT TOP 1
             @SourceParameterTemplateID = [SourceParameterTemplateID]
       FROM  INSERTED AS I
       WHERE     NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                        FROM     [AVData].[dbo].[SourceParameterTemplate]
                             AS A
                        WHERE    I.[SourceParameterTemplateID] = A.[SourceParameterTemplateID] )
       ORDER BY [SourceParameterTemplateID]

       IF @SourceParameterTemplateID IS NOT NULL 
          BEGIN
             DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(250)
             set @msg = 'Violation of foreign key constraint for SourceParameterTemplateID: ' + CAST(@SourceParameterTemplateID AS VARCHAR(50))
             RAISERROR(@msg,16,1);
             ROLLBACK;
          END
    END
```

Comment: It ran the trigger and I received the "Violation of foreign key constraint" however there was nothing in the place of @SourceParameterTemplateID

Comment: You can only pass a variable to the first field, the field you are currently using only works for a fixed string value and is generally used for the stored procedure/trigger name. I have updated the post to construct a message including the ID value.

Comment: I was just posting a comment where I did the same thing. Thank-you for your for all your help Jaco.